# firestore remove documents by field value

Tags: vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

each of my docs in my firestore db contains 1 field {name: 'some value'}

I would like to loop through all the docs and then if the doc's fields value is equal to my param I would like to remove that doc

I'm trying to do it like so:

```
removeContact: function(name){
      console.log('removing contact',name)

      db.collection("contacts").forEach(doc=>{
        if(doc.data().name === name){
          doc.delete()
        }
      })

    }
```

but I get the error that forEach() is not defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To delete a document, you need to know the full path to that document. And since you don't know the document IDs, that means you'll first need to read the documents.

The good news is that this means you can also perform a query to filter only the documents you're interesting in, instead of doing an client-side `if`.

```
db.collection("contacts").where("name", "==", name)
  .get()
  .then((querySnapshot) => {
    querySnapshot.forEach(doc=>{
      doc.ref.delete()
    })
  })
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `.get()` following the collection or query to get a query snapshot **promise**, which you then handle accordingly. You can use `forEach` on the snapshot and delete each doc.

A better way, instead of searching through every document and using an if statement, would be to use a query like `where('name', '==', name)` and delete the document that way. Using a query would leave less for your function to do.

Comment: thanks christopher, I was missing the promise and that caught me up :)